# Spring boot : adding XML support

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Using STS, I create a simple Spring Starter project, and try add dependy for Jackson XML support

see: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Whatever twist I try (changing spring-starter release version) I always get the same error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

In STS, whem looking at *resolved* dependency, I can clearly see that **org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api** is present.

:[image: resolved dependencies]

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.text</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloJackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>HelloJackson</name>
    <description>HelloWorld</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: **I can clearly see that org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api is present.**
Why i cannot find it?

Comment: see added image

Comment: Yes, but please add a dependency in your pom too. I have written an answer for you.

Comment: you don't have to re-add the dependency, just change the scope of the old one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this means the class `org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2` not required at compile time but it is required at runtime,(may be other dependency use it ).
try to add to the pom file

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It worked, but I am not sure why its need to be re-added. It's already a dependency (and a dependency of a dependency)

Comment: as i can see from the image, yes it is already exist on dependency list, but you can see it is compile scoped (the compile word between square braces [compile]) that means it will be used only on compile, not on runtime, so you can change the scope of the already added dependency  and it will run.

Comment: well, it is my understanding that compile scope is included in the runtime classpath  : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: Seems like the problem was that the JAR was corrupted. Adding another version fixed the problem, because it forced to download another JAR. I purge the local repo, and everything works as it should

Comment: @Filip, you are right i missed the point of maven compile scope

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem was that the JAR was corrupted. Adding another version fixed the problem, because it forced to download another JAR. I purged the local repo, and everything worked as it should